# Todoist API Get all items with the required tag

Tags: php, api, todoist

I want get from todoist api (https://developer.todoist.com/sync/v7/) all items with required tag (label).

At the moment I'm getting all the entries here that way:

```
$url = "https://todoist.com/api/v7/sync";
$post_data = [
    'token' => "token",
    'sync_token' => "*",
    'resource_types' => '["items"]'
];
```

Of course, I can do this on PHP, but if there is a possibility of filtering by means of api, then this is the best option.

**My question - how i can get items with specific tag (label)?..**

Comment: Hello & Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please rad http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... In fact, your "question" isn't even a question, there is no `?` or anything. Its totally unclear what you want to achieve and how we should help you. Also make sure that you've understand that stackoverflow is here to HELP you with specific programming problems, but not to code for you. Show us your code, show us what you've tried and we'll help you. But nobody will write code for you.

Comment: i have corrected

Answer (score 0):

The current API does not support these kinds of filters, so you should do it in your PHP code for now.

Comment: I think you can filter now.

Comment: Yes, you can do it using the REST API these days. :)